Pause Menu Help Unity
I know this question has been asked many times but mine seems to be slightly different. I am having trouble locking the camera rotation when entering the pause menu. I have tried looking at every single other similar question but those did not help. Hopefully this will. I have attached my scripts.
Pause menu Script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool paused = false;
    public GameObject PauseMenuCanvas;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (paused)
            {
                Play();
            }
            else
            {
                Stop();
            }
        }
    }
    
    void Stop()
    {
        PauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        paused = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None; 
    }
    
    public void Play()
    {
        PauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        paused = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    
    void MainMenuButton()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
    }
}

Player Script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("Configurations")]
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float runSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;

    [Header("References")]
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform head;
    public Camera camera;

    [Header("Runtime")]
    Vector3 newVelocity;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    bool isJumping = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        // Hide and lock the mouse cursor
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
       // Horizontal rotation
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2f);

       newVelocity = Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;
       float speed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed;
       newVelocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
       newVelocity.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
       
       if (isGrounded) {
           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping) {
               newVelocity.y = jumpSpeed;
               isJumping = true;
            }
       }
       rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(newVelocity);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        // Shoot a ray of 1 unit towards the ground
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 1f)) {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
        else isGrounded = false;
    }

    void LateUpdate(){
        //Vertical rotation
        Vector3 e = head.eulerAngles;
        e.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") *2f;
        e.x = RestrictAngle(e.x, -85f, 85f);
        head.eulerAngles = e;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay(Collision col) {
        if (Vector3.Dot(col.GetContact(0).normal, Vector3.up) <= .6f)
            return;
        
        isGrounded = true;
        isJumping = false;
    }

    //Clamp the vertical head roatation
    public static float RestrictAngle(float angle, float angleMin, float angleMax) {
        if (angle > 180)
            angle -= 360;
        else if (angle < -180)
            angle += 360;

        if (angle > angleMax)
            angle = angleMax;
        if (angle < angleMin)
            angle = angleMin;

        return angle;
    }
}

I tried to look at the other peoples problems but all of them use the built in Unity Player. I created this FPS on my own so I don't know what to do. I am very far in the process of making a game and would not like to replace my FPS controller because it has so many other components attached to it. If you would like any other information feel free to ask but I just can not seem to find a solution to this problem. I know it has something to do with the time scale and delta time but I am new to this and am trying to learn more. Sorry for adding another pause menu question to the mix.

What exactly is the problem? What is it supposed to do and what does it do now?

First question then - please defeine how asre you not using the built in player? second, you're applying physics in update? but doing a raycast in fixedupdate??

you have one of two ways
first is to change your player script to match your new mechanic of pause menu like this
void Update(){
   // Horizontal rotation
   if(Time.timeScale!=0)
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2f);
   .
   .
   .
}
void LateUpdate(){
    if(Time.timeScale==0)
        return 
    //Vertical rotation
    Vector3 e = head.eulerAngles;
    e.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") *2f;
    e.x = RestrictAngle(e.x, -85f, 85f);
    head.eulerAngles = e;
}

or you can create another camera that doesn't move at all and deactivate your game camera and then activate the other camera. I would manage them in the PauseMenu class.
I'd reccomend the seccond solution but If you want to make it work fast, just use the the first solution

In general: People don't use built-in things only but rather solved issues like that a lot of times already.
You should go event driven and expose an event like e.g.
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // going static here to focus on the mechanics only
    // in general you should avoid this and rather have proper reference management
    public static event Action<bool> pauseStateChanged;

    void Stop()
    {
        ...

        pauseStateChanged?.Invoke(true);    
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        ...

        pauseStateChanged?.Invoke(false);
    }
}

and then your player can subscribe to it and be completely deactivated
public class PlayerController : MonoBehavior 
{
    ...


    void Awake()
    {
        ...

        PauseMenu.pauseStateChanged += OnPauseMenu;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        PauseMenu.pauseStateChanged -= OnPauseMenu;
    }

    private void OnPauseMenu(bool isPaused)
    {
        enabled = !isPaused;
    }
}

So why would this work? Because once you simply disable your script message methods like Update, FixedUpdate etc are not called anymore.
Where needed you can then additionally check for
if(!enabled) return;

and if required implement additional reactions directly in OnEnable and OnDisable, for example if there is a Rigidbody component you want to enable and disable along with your script

For advanced reactive approaches check out UniRX
